# p2os setup failed... for Hydro

Tags: serial, ros-hydro, pioneer-3dx, p2os-driver, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been working through the [p2os-vanderbilt setup tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/p2os-vanderbilt/Tutorials/Setup) and have been having many issues.  I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Hydro and a Pioneer 3-DX connected to my SlimPro via serial comm port.

I have successfully installed and compiled the p2os and the pr2 controllers packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-p2os-driver ros-hydro-p2os-teleop ros-hydro-p2os-launch ros-hydro-p2os-urdf
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-pr2-controllers ros-groovy-joystick-drivers
cd ~/catkin_ws/src && git clone https://github.com/allenh1/p2os.git  /*note different from tutorial*/
git clone https://github.com/allenh1/vanderbilt-ros-pkg.git          /*note different from tutorial*/
source ../devel/setup.bash
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make
```

When I try:

```
rosrun p2os_driver p2os_driver
```

so I can then enable the motor, I get an error:

```
[ INFO] [1417478313.806461148]: using serial port: [/dev/ttyS0]
[ INFO] [1417478313.835717295]: P2OS connection opening serial port /dev/ttyS0...
[ERROR] [1417478313.835785839]: P2OS::Setup():open():
[ERROR] [1417478313.835822762]: p2os setup failed...
```

I went into ~/catkin_ws/src/p2os/p2os_driver/include/p2os_driver/robot_param.h and changed the DEFAULT_P2OS_PORT "/dev/ttyS0" to DEFAULT_P2OS_PORT "/dev/tty0" and changed the ros parameter with:

```
rosparam set /p2os/port /dev/tty0
```

and I got the same issue as before (except the error read "tty0" instead).  I've tried enabling the motor before and after running the p2os_driver.

Your help in this matter is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

On a side note, does anyone know where I can find the p2os_dashboard for Hydro?  Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198667/p2os-setup-failed...-for-hydro/) by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 323 on 2014-12-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been emailing back and forth with Hunter Allen of Vanderbilt.

I simply had to use this command:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/ttyS0
```

and it began working.

Additionally, if you are using a USB connection, use the following:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I have tested it out successfully with the [C++ Velocity Node](http://wiki.ros.org/p2os-vanderbilt/Tutorials/C%2B%2B%20Velocity%20Controller%20for%20P2OS%20Robots) from the p2os-vanderbilt tutorials (with a few minor adjustments).

Thanks for all your help y'all.

---

Originally posted by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) with karma: 323 on 2014-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-12-04**:
If this solves your problem, please mark this answer as correct.

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2014-12-04**:
Sorry.  You must have greater than 25 points to mark your own answer as correct...I will once I get there.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-12-04**:
Now you should be fine.